# Brackets around command in unix shell

Tags: macos, unix, xerces-c

What mean brackets around command in the unix shell. For example:

```
mac: workdir$pwd
/Users/Alex/workdir
same output of this:
mac: workdir$(pwd)
/Users/Alex/workdir
```

What is the difference when I'm use brackets and don't use it? My really situation it is:

```
(CP)  /Users/Alex/workdir/xercesc/include/xercesc/util.
```

I'm trying to build `xercesc` for mac os, and take few troubles. And I'm trying to do some changes in make package.

Comment: My problem is that I do not understand why can command will be listed in brackets.

Comment: I'm still unclear what your problem is. The example you've included doesn't seem to have any 'bracket' characters included. Are you referring to `(CP)` as the "the brackets"?  Please clarify if you mean square brackets [..] or curly brackets {...}, OR ....some other kind of brackets? This isn't really a programming question, voting to move to superuser.com. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea what `workdir` is but `$pwd` does nothing at all unless `$pwd` is a variable that you set, and `$(pwd)` calls the command `pwd` in a subshell.  The `pwd` command prints the current working directory.

For what it's worth, I wouldn't recommend setting using `$pwd` as a variable since it is a built-in `POSIX` command.

Lastly, these `{ } [ ]` are brackets and these `( )` are parenthesis.